# `pow` not returning (IEEE)denormalized floating-point numbers?

Tags: c++, c

Why does `pow` (`math.h` or `cmath`) not returning denormalized numbers? For example, this:

```
float f = pow (2.f, -126);
double d = pow (2.0, -1022);
```

gives a non-zero answer for `f` and `d`, but using a smaller exponent, i.e -127 for `f` and `-1023` for `d`, returns a zero, although even `2 ^ -149` (for singles) and `2 ^ -1074` (for doubles) are still representable (as IEEE-754 'denormalized').

Compiler is Microsoft's VS2008, debug config.

Comment: If your intent is academic, I don't know. If this has practical importance, consider using `std::ldexp`.

Comment: Which compiler? Which switches? On GCC you would want to avoid -fcx-limited-range which is also implied by -ffast-math.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info, I've edited my question.

Comment: Does this line even compile? "float f = pow (2.f, -126);"

Comment: why wouldn't it compile? it does.

Comment: @ItamarKatz:
Just for your information,
`pow` with an argument from -1023 to -1074 for `double` and
`powf` with an argument from -126 to -149 for `float`
return non-zero value in VC2005 DEBUG config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like VC is flushing denormals.  This can be controlled by the following:

```
#include <float.h>
#pragma fenv_access (on)

int main()
{
    _controlfp(_DN_SAVE, _MCW_DN);
    float f = pow (2.f, -127);
    double d = pow (2.0, -1023);
}
```

Comment: I am working on a large project with more developers, and it turns out the flag for the SSE unit to flush denorms was set to ON in some cpp file I was not aware of. Thanks!